# How do I get the *actual* host application instance?

Tags: c#, office-interop, vbe

I have this code in a C# add-in for the VBE (emphasis "VBE": it's **not** a MS-Office add-in):

```
public abstract class HostApplicationBase<TApplication> : IHostApplication
    where TApplication : class
{
    protected readonly TApplication Application;
    protected HostApplicationBase(string applicationName)
    {
        Application = (TApplication)Marshal.GetActiveObject(applicationName + ".Application");
    }
```

Where `TApplication` is a MS-Office interop `Application` class, for example, a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` type; here the `applicationName` parameter would be "Excel" for, well, Excel.

The problem is that `Marshal.GetActiveObject` seems to only ever return the *first* instance created, and that's not necessarily the instance that's hosting the current VBE environment, and [this causes issues](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/811).

How can I get ahold of the *actual* host application instance?

Comment: Possible duplicate, but the answers are nothing more than links. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13432057/3198973

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of slaying a zombie, you can get the *name* of the VBE's host by:

- Inspecting the caption of the CommandBarButton that takes you to the host. The button is on the Standard Toolbar, but also in the View Menu.
- Inspecting the names of the references. Typically the first reference that isn't VBA but is `BuiltIn`.
- Inspecting the Application.Name property of document component's Properties collection.

And to reliably get a reference to the VBE's host, you have to use the Properties collection of the document-type components. For example, once you know that the *name* of the host is "Microsoft Excel", you just need to find the Workbook document-component (typically named ThisWorkbook), then you can get the host from the component's Properties collection.

```
            var appProperty = vbe.VBProjects
                .Cast<VBProject>()
                .Where(project => project.Protection == vbext_ProjectProtection.vbext_pp_none)
                .SelectMany(project => project.VBComponents.Cast<VBComponent>())
                .Where(component => component.Type == vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_Document
                && component.Properties.Count > 1)
                .SelectMany(component => component.Properties.OfType<Property>())
                .FirstOrDefault(property => property.Name == "Application");
            if (appProperty != null)
            {
                Application = (TApplication)appProperty.Object;
            }
            else
            {
                Application = (TApplication)Marshal.GetActiveObject(applicationName + ".Application");
            }
```

But not all vbProjects have document-type components, so for such projects you'll have to resort to the `GetActiveObject` approach.