# VBE Add-In - How to do a "Save All"

Tags: c#, add-in, vbe

Im writing an AddIn in C# for the VBA-Development-Environment (VBE) in ms-access. (See also here: [Build add-in for VBA IDE using VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942626/build-add-in-for-vba-ide-using-vb-net/51288795) ).

The VDE does not save its code moduls when starting an VBA-Program. As Im implementing a "Start Programm"-Button, I want to save all the code (Forms, Classmoduls and Modules) when starting (Similar to e.g. in Visual studio when hitting "Start debug" or build).

There is a "Saved" flag in the VBProject-class, but I cant find a "Save"-function or something similar.

But I cant find how to do this (I generally have problems finding something in the microsoft documentation - or even finding the offical microsoft class documentation for C# - but this is another point).

So: How do I save a code module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did this with:

```
var app = GetApp();
app.DoCmd.RunCommand(AcCommand.acCmdCompileAndSaveAllModules);
```

but there is also a Command

```
AcCommand.acCmdSaveAllModules
```

if you dont want to compile.

The function GetApp is more complicated. I did this with the answer from here: [How to get the correct active Application from a VBE-Add-In?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51704164/how-to-get-the-correct-active-application-from-a-vbe-add-in)